# Matching route with parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, episerver

I'm new working with routes.

Some one know what this route doesn't work.

/dispatch/Paris/Lixo = page not found

/dispatch?region=Paris&department=Lixo //works.

**Global.asax:**

```
        routes.MapContentRoute(name: "customRoute",
                        url: "{region}/{department}",
                        defaults: new { 
    action = "index", 
    controller = "dispatch", 
    region = UrlParameter.Optional, 
    department = UrlParameter.Optional
}
                        //,contentRootResolver: (s) => s.StartPage
                        );
```

**DispatchController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Index(DispatchPage currentPage, string region, string department)
```

Comment: I recommend looking into EPiServer's partial routing, specifically the [News partial routing](http://world.episerver.com/Documentation/Items/Developers-Guide/EPiServer-CMS/75/Routing/Partial-routing/Example-of-News-partial-routing/) example. Since you are doing this in an EPiServer solution, standard MVC routing is not going to work the same way, unless you completely forgo creating your controllers as EPiServer page type controllers. Also, I'd suggest posting your question to the EPiServer World forums, which will give your question better exposure to EPiServer developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your route includes only region and department. The URL does not assume controller is there. Also, I assume, there is a default route defined. So:

`/dispatch/Paris/Lixo` - does not fit anything. `{region}/{department}` does not have controller, so route processor assigns `dispatch` to `region` and `Paris` to `department`. `Luxo` does not fit anything, therefore the whole route does not fit. On the other hand default route assumes `Paris` is an action, so it does not fit as well.

`/dispatch?region=Paris&department=Lixo` - fits default route with action set by default. Notice that query string params do not play any role in routing, except they are passed along, well, as parameters.

What you are probably after is, I think, this route:

```
url: "dispatch/{region}/{department}"
```

This will capture the first url just fine.